# How to Fire WebBrowserDocumentCompleted event from default Web Browser

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

I tried two method:

1. `wb.Navigate(Url,true);` When i use this webbrowser appear but `WebBrowserDocumentCompleted` event doesn't fire after page loaded.
2. `wb.Navigate(Url);` When i use this `WebBrowserDocumentCompleted` event is firing but browser doesn't appear on screen. How can i display external browser and fire `WebBrowserDocumentCompleted` event same time?

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
       wb.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
       wb.Visible = true;
       wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
       wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
       wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com",true);
   }

   private void WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       if ((sender as WebBrowser).ReadyState == System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
       {
           // Do what ever you want to do here when page is completely loaded.
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: 1: passing *true* tells it to create a new browser window and not use yours.  2: is correct, the code is simply missing this.Controls.Add(wb) to make it a visible child of the form.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. After i filled texboxes I want to display on new browser window. I dont want to add control inside form. Is it possible?

Comment: It is not impossible with the native COM object.  But WebBrowser was meant to be used as a child control.  It is not clear why you don't simply display another Form if you want a "new browser window".